# Trying to set JScrollPane height to 100% without stretching container?

Tags: css

I have a middle container that takes up whatever vertical space is left on the screen. In it, I placed a Jquery scroller that is currently set to 200px:

```
.scroll-pane
{
width: 100%;
height: 200px;
overflow: auto;
}
.horizontal-only
{
height: auto;
max-height: 100%;
}
```

However, if I set `.scroll-pane` height to 100%, it just removes the scrollbar and stretches the whole page.

[See JsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/je7ZP/)

How can I stop this? Thanks!

Comment: I changed `.scroll-pane` height to 100% in the fiddle and I'm not getting the behavior you are. For me it is working how I think you are intending it to. http://imgur.com/hABEr -- This may be a browser issue

Comment: Darn it. This is the second time that Firefox 15 has caused an issue. Do you think there's any way around this, since I'm guessing that the latest version of Firefox is probably very popular?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution to this problem ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/je7ZP/3/)). It uses markup like this:

```
<div id="top">...</div>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="middle">...</div>
</div>
<div id="bottom">...</div>
```

The `top` and `bottom` divs are position absolutely at the top and bottom, with a `width` of `100%`. The wrapper `div` has `height: 100%`, `box-sizing: border-box`, and top and bottom padding equal to the height of the top and bottom divs, respectively. This causes it to fill the viewport but have padding underneath the top and bottom divs. The `middle` div has a height of `100%` so it fills the content box of the wrapper (i.e., `100%` minus the top and bottom paddings). It has `position: relative`, which leaves you free to use `height: 100%` on both interior boxes.

Lastly, `middleleft` is positioned absolutely and `middleright` has a left margin equal to its width, which causes it to fill the remaining horizontal space.

Answer (score 2):

`height: 100%` never works like you want it to. The CSS specifications dictate that it must equal the height of the browser window, or the closest parent block-level element with an *absolute* height specified. That means that this code <strike>will</strike> *should* not work as expected:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Want the body to fill the page? Too bad!</title>
  <style type="text/css">
   html, body {
    height: 100%;
   }
   .page {
    padding-top: 50px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100%;
   }
   .header {
    margin-top: -50px;
    height: 50px;
   }
   .body {
    height: 100%;
    background: gray;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="page">
   <div class="header">
    <h1>Too bad!</h1>
   </div>
   <div class="body">
    <p>Hello cruel world...</p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

However, that works fine in Chrome. Why? I can only assume that Google decided to **specifically go against web standards** because in this case, the standards ***make no sense***. Why would I want something to be the exact height of the browser window? The only time is a `<div>` wrapping the whole page; in this case a simple "height is relative to the parent block" rule works just fine without breaking expectations elsewhere.

There is a way around this, though. At least, that's what I wanted to say before I tried this in Firefox too. Another way to get `height: 100%` (with some restrictions) is with `position: absolute`. However, it would seem that Firefox isn't respecting `position: relative` on a `display: table-cell` element - probably those pesky standards again. Here's the code for this technique anyway, if you are interested:

```
#wrapper > div > #middleleft {
 position: relative;
}
.scroll-pane {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
}
```

So what can you do? Well, unfortunately, I don't yet know the answer to that. A kludgy solution would be to have Javascript set the height to an absolute pixel value, and attach an event to window resizing in order to update that height. I'll get back to you if I find a better way.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what your trying to do, but another method would be to set body height to 100%, then set scrollpane to "height: auto". Then for the "top" and "bottom" div's used fixed positioning, plus margin equal to top/bottom height.

```
body {
    height: 100%;
}
.top {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    height: 100px;
}
.middle {
    height: auto;
    margin: 100px auto;
}
.bottom {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
   height: 100px;
}

<div class="top">content</div>
<div class="middle">content</div>
<div class="bottom">content</div>
```

Try that...